# Is this a tensor field?

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm trying to understand the finer points of a tensor field. One definition which seems to work for me is that a tensor field is just a set of scalar fields assigned to a point/event on a manifold. So, obviously, the tensor can contain information about the energy flux through a given point, but (as I understand it) a tensor field can contain other properties too. Is this a valid tensor field?

$$\begin{bmatrix}v_0 & v_1 & v_2 & v_3 \\\\ a_0 & a_1 & a_2 & a_3 \\\\ j_1 & j_2 & j_3 & j_4 \end{bmatrix}$$
I'm reasonably sure that $\boldsymbol{v}$, the velocity vector, is a valid tensor field, so is $\boldsymbol{a}$ the acceleration vector and $\boldsymbol{j}$ the jerk (third derivative of location with respect to time) also valid components of a tensor field?

Comment: Your definition of a tensor field is simply wrong. What textbook are you reading? If it is written by/for physicists, you should use it only as a supplement to a math differential geometry book.

Comment: @MoisheKohan - From the Wiki Page on Tensor Fields: "*As a tensor is a generalization of a scalar (a pure number representing a value, for example speed) and a vector (a pure number plus a direction, like velocity), a tensor field is a generalization of a scalar field or vector field that assigns, respectively, a scalar or vector to each point of space"*

Comment: That's their warm-up and less than half of the truth. Read the whole article patiently and a good book about DG or GR. In short: Tensor fields have transformation properties that allow to view them as coordinate independent (as you said). Clearly not every bunch of numbers can be a tensor field.

Comment: @KurtG. Thanks for the suggestion. I've read Gravity, I've searched the internet, that's how I was able to form this question and that's why I'm here: to ask questions about subjects not explicitly covered in the textbook. "*Clearly not every bunch of numbers can be a tensor field"* I agree. Is my example a tensor field and, if not, can you explain to me why not?

Comment: Do you know what a topological/smooth manifold is? How much linear algebra do you know? Do you know what a bundle is? For a reference, you might have a look at [Lee's book](https://books.google.com.mx/books/about/Introduction_to_Smooth_Manifolds.html?id=xygVcKGPsNwC&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button&hl=en&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false). There is a very nice chapter on tensor fields.

Comment: I recapitulate in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4313025/949989) a few basic facts from Sean Carroll, *Spacetime and Geometry*: 1) The four-velocity $U^\mu$ is a 1st rank tensor. 2) So is the four-acceleration $A^\nu=U^\mu\nabla_\mu U^\nu\,.$ 3) Feel free to apply this pattern to generate jerk: $J^\nu=U^\mu\nabla_\mu A^\nu$ which is another 1st rank tensor. The point is that the matrix you put together is *not* a 2nd rank tensor. It is a bunch of 1st rank tensors.

Comment: @KurtG. *"The point is that the matrix you put together is not a 2nd rank tensor. It is a bunch of 1st rank tensors."* And there you have the essence of my question. Isn't a second rank tensor exactly that? A bunch of 1st rank tensors?

Comment: Seems like we get to the bottom of the question now :). No it is not exactly that. For higher rank tensors the transformation rules go with their rank. I cannot explain this here in a comment but the book I highly recommended nicely explains it.

Comment: @KurtG. Which book is that? I only see Lee's book recommended by Matematleta.

Comment: Lee's book is quite famous and mentioned often here in MSE but I admit that I did not read it. As a pedestrian I enjoyed Sean Carroll's *Spacetime and  Geometry* mentioned above. I believe there is still a free teaser/trailer of it somewhere in the internet. Even in a reliable site: https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9712019